# cscope results in multiple definitions when searching for a class (cpp code)

Tags: c++, vim, cscope

vim+cscope on Linux host works well for my earlier project which has only C code. But I am facing problems using vim+cscope in new project which is C++ based.

Problem I am facing is, when I search for definition of a class using Ctrl+G it shows the definitions of all the member functions along with class definition.

For example,

```
class test {
                 int foo(void);
                 int bar(void);
}
```

Ctrl+G on `test` is showing the definition of `foo, bar` functions and `test` class. Where as I am only interested in the definition of the `test` class. This problem becomes much bigger when there are 20-30 member functions inside a class definition.

Is there anyway I can change settings/configuration to directly go to the definition of a class when I click Ctrl+G on the class name ?

Comment: You could start by investigating why and how you get that feature mapped to `Ctrl+G` in the first place: `:verbose map <c-g>`.

Comment: I have only set that mapping. That is the general mapping used for vim and cscope to work together. But my question is not why Ctrl+G is showing global definitions of a symbol. My question is, why search for the global definition of a C++ class is showing the definitions of member functions of a class.

Comment: Ctrl+G means nothing: you could have mapped it to any command. You are asking why the command you mapped to Ctrl+G is acting up *without* telling us what's that command. And without much reduced example/screenshot.

Comment: ok, I have used the vim+cscope mappings to use cscope functionalities within the Vim. " nmap <C-\>g :cs find g <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR> "

Comment: And its not just with Ctrl+G. I have a `tags` file generated using `ctags` utility. Search for definition of a class using `ctags` feature i.e. " Ctrl+} " also showing the definitions of member functions in the results.

Comment: `<C-\>g` is not Ctrl+G, it's Ctrl+\ then G. How are your members indexed? As `test.foo()`?

Comment: You are right about the key combination. I did not type it properlt but I use the combination which you have mentioned. Yes, class members are indexed in general C++ manner. `object.member_function` or `pointer_to_object->member_function`. Sorry, I didn't get your question.

Comment: Wow, nobody seems to use vim & cscope to work on cpp project. I thought this is pretty common scenario. Anyone still there who can answer my question ? Please feel free to ask more details if required.